# Access array in another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I have a storyboard laid out like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to be able to input a number on the shortcut view controller (bottom row, middle position) and use that number to filter an array that exists on the Hymns View controller (top right).

This should return an array with 1 result, being an instance of my model, Hymn, so that i can show the detail view. (bottom right).

Starting with inputting a number on my shortcut controller, how can I access the hymns array created on the viewDidLoad method from the table view controller, on my detail view controller?

Comment: you can keep the array in AppDelegate and you can access it anywhere (which is pretty basic way) other one would be to create an array as property in the receiving controller and in `prepareForSegue` pass the array from sender controller to receiver.

Comment: @samfisher The problem here is the Tab Bar Controller: the predicate is given in the "Search" Pane, while the filtered array will be displayed in the "Hinos" pane. Switching from one tab to the other would not invoke the segue. That is, we need some notification mechanism where the Search pane notifies the change of the predicate and where the "Hinos" observes this notification. Alternatively, the Search pane performs the filtering in the model, and notifies a change of the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that array in Model to use it on the shortcut controller

Comment: If i'm extracting data from an XML to populate my model, should the code to extracting it be ran in the model?

Comment: You can have a separate sharedInstance model for saving the array. Are you using the the populated model values to create that array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array as extern and use it in any class in your project.

```
extern NSMutableArray *sample;
```